# Setting up the serial object from a function (called from tkinter interaction)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, serial-port, pyserial

I managed to get my tkinter aplication to display text on a text field.

I did this by hardcoding the COM port and baud rate, then set up a serial object at the beginning of my program.

```
baudRate = 9600
ser = serial.Serial('COM16', baudRate)
```

Then all my code runs afterwards.

But the problem with this is that everything is hardcoded.
I want the user to be able to select the COM port from a dropdown.
And when he selects one port, the serial communication should start.

So i built exactly that. Here is my relevant code.

```
#hardcoded baud rate
baudRate = 9600

# this is the global variable that will hold the serial object value
ser = 0 #initial  value. will change at 'on_select()'

#this function populates the dropdown on frame1, with all the serial ports of the system
def serial_ports():    
    return serial.tools.list_ports.comports()

#when the user selects one serial port from the dropdown, this function will execute
def on_select(event=None):
    global ser
    COMPort = cb.get()
    string_separator = "-"
    COMPort = COMPort.split(string_separator, 1)[0] #remove everything after '-' character
    COMPort = COMPort[:-1] #remove last character of the string (which is a space)
    ser = serial.Serial(port = COMPort, baudrate=9600)
    return ser
    readSerial() #start reading

#this function reads the incoming data and inserts them into a text frame
def readSerial():
    ser_bytes = ser.readline()
    ser_bytes = ser_bytes.decode("utf-8")
    text.insert("end", ser_bytes)
    if vsb.get()[1]==1.0:
       text.see("end")
    root.after(100, readSerial)
```

What happens when i select a COM port from the dropdown, is that i see transmision on the led buttons of my device.

However, nothing is displayed on the text frame. Before, when i hardcoded everything and setup the serialobject in the beginning of the program, and i statre the `readSerial()` function in the end of my program, everything worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `on_select` function, you have called `return` before calling the `readSerial()` function. The `return` statement terminates the execution of a function, any statements following it will not be executed. Removing it would make the program work.

Also, since `on_select` is a callback form the dropdown, the `return` statement is redundant as it does not have anywhere to return to. The `global ser` takes care of assigning the new value to the `ser` variable globally.

You do not need to call the `readSerial()` function every time a new option is selected (else, it will increase the number of scheduled calls every time). You can either have a button that calls it once you have initially configured it and remove the call to `readSerial()` form `on_select` or create a flag that ensures that it has been called only once.

---

Based on your comment, I've created the following example, you could try something like this

```py
from tkinter import *

def on_select(event):
    global value
    value=option.get()
    if stop_:
        start_button['state']='normal'

def start():
    global stop_
    stop_=False
    readSerial()
    start_button['state']='disabled'
    stop_button['state']='normal'

def stop():
    global stop_
    stop_=True
    root.after_cancel(after_id)
    start_button['state']='normal'
    stop_button['state']='disabled'

def readSerial():
    global after_id
    text.insert(END,value)
    after_id=root.after(100,readSerial)

root=Tk()

text=Text(root)
text.pack(side='bottom')

options=['1','2']
option=StringVar()
om=OptionMenu(root,option,*options,command=on_select)
om.pack(side='left')

start_button=Button(root,text='start',command=start,state='disabled')
start_button.pack(side='left')
stop_button=Button(root,text='stop',command=stop,state='disabled')
stop_button.pack(side='left')

stop_=True

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Great explanation

Comment: I am trying to figure it out. 1. Remove the return statement completely. About your third paragraph though... I didn't quite get it... In my code, i have to be also be able to stop the readSerial() function. Because my arduino program wil only send data when trigger. So when i send the STOP TRANSMIT commands from tkinter, i will also have to stop the readSerial(). Wo what is the best approach. Maybe a button that will initiate the serial communication by setting the serial object. And another button that will start the readSerial() and set up a flag, and another button that will send the

Comment: StopTransmit command to the arduino, but it also has to stop the readSerial(), is it possible?

Comment: @user1584421 I have updated the answer with an example, I believe you are looking for something similar to that, let me know if that helps.

Comment: Is this code valid to do? In readSerial(), when the flag (stop_) is set to True, the two lines will not execute. So it will not print to the text field. But if root.after(100,readSerial) has already been initiated, then your readSerial() function will not stop its execution. Shouldn't your readSerial() also contain code to actively stop the periodic execution, if it has already been initiated? I saw that _cancel does that. So maybe readSerial() will turn a flag to True, and the stop button will check if that True is set, and if it is, it will call the _cancel function on the id.

Comment: @user1584421 Even if there is a call scheduled, nothing would happen since the flag is true, and `after` will not be called anymore so no future calls will be scheduled and the loop would break resulting in stopped execution. The only problem that could arise is that if start+stop+start is done within `100ms` a new cycle can be created, which would result in twice the number of calls, you can use `after_cancel` to make it more robust, I have updated the code implementing the same.

Comment: @AST I have a similar question with an open bounty. Care to take a look at it? It's here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67040731/unable-to-read-serial-data-without-errors-bugs