# Program stucks when sending serial data

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pyserial

I am developing a small application, in roder to interface with my arduino.

However, in order for the arduino to start sending serial data, i have to trigger it with a specific string.

When i press the button that will send the string and will initiate the serial read, the program stucks.
No error is shown on the terminal.

Here is the relevant code:

```
    #setting the serial object
    def on_select(event=None):
        global ser
        COMPort = cb.get()
        ser = serial.Serial(port = COMPort, baudrate=9600)
    
   # read serial data
    def readSerial():
        ser_bytes = ser.readline()
        ser_bytes = ser_bytes.decode("utf-8")
        text.insert("end", ser_bytes)
        after_id=root.after(100,readSerial)
    
    # this function is triggered, when button 'Measure all Sensors' is pressed, on frame 2
    def measure_all():    
       global stop
       stop_ = False
       ser.write(str.encode('rf')) #Send string 'rf to arduino', which means Measure all Sensors
       readSerial() #Start Reading data
```

The first two functions work, because i gave been able to read serial data, when the arduino just spits data, without requiring activation by sending it text.

It's the third function that makes the program stuck somehow.

EDIT: This is more code - the bigger picture.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import serial.tools.list_ports #for a list of all the COM ports
from tkinter import scrolledtext

#to be used on our canvas
HEIGHT = 800
WIDTH = 800

#hardcoded baud rate
baudRate = 9600

# this is the global variable that will hold the serial object value
ser = None #initial  value. will change at 'on_select()'

# --- functions ---

#the following two functtions are for the seria port selection, on frame 1

#this function populates the combobox on frame1, with all the serial ports of the system
def serial_ports():    
    return serial.tools.list_ports.comports()


#when the user selects one serial port from the combobox, this function will execute
def on_select(event=None):
    global ser
    COMPort = cb.get()
    string_separator = "-"
    COMPort = COMPort.split(string_separator, 1)[0] #remove everything after '-' character
    COMPort = COMPort[:-1] #remove last character of the string (which is a space)
    ser = serial.Serial(port = COMPort, baudrate=9600)

def readSerial():
    ser_bytes = ser.readline()
    ser_bytes = ser_bytes.decode("utf-8")
    text.insert("end", ser_bytes)
    if vsb.get()[1]==1.0: #if the scrollbar is down to the bottom, then autoscroll
       text.see("end")
    after_id=root.after(100,readSerial)



# this function is triggered, when button 'Measure all Sensors' is pressed, on frame 2
def measure_all():    
   global stop_
   stop_ = False
   button_stop['state']='normal' #make the 'Stop Measurement' button accessible
   ser.write("rf".encode()) #Send string 'rf to arduino', which means Measure all Sensors
   readSerial() #Start Reading data


# --- main ---
root = tk.Tk() #here we create our tkinter window
root.title("Sensor Interface")

#we use canvas as a placeholder, to get our initial screen size (we have defined HEIGHT and WIDTH)
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

# --- frame 1 ---
frame1 = tk.Frame(root)
frame1.place(relx=0, rely=0.05, relheight=0.03, relwidth=1, anchor='nw') #we use relheight and relwidth to fill whatever the parent is - in this case- root

label0 = tk.Label(frame1, text="Select the COM port that the device is plugged in: ")
label0.config(font=("TkDefaultFont", 8))
label0.place(relx = 0.1, rely=0.3, relwidth=0.3, relheight=0.5)


cb = ttk.Combobox(frame1, values=serial_ports())
cb.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')
cb.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', on_select)
# --- frame 1 ---

# --- frame 2 ---
frame2 = tk.Frame(root, bd=5) #REMOVED THIS bg='#80c1ff' (i used it to see the borders of the frame)
frame2.place(relx=0, rely=0.1, relheight=0.07, relwidth=1, anchor='nw')

#Button for 'Measure All Sensors'
#it will be enabled initially
button_all = tk.Button(frame2, text="Measure all Sensors", bg='#80c1ff', fg='red', state='normal', command=measure_all)  #bg='gray'
button_all.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.5, anchor='center')


#frame 6 will be the area with the texct field
# --- frame 6 ---
frame6 = tk.Frame(root, bg='#80c1ff') #remove color later
frame6.place(relx=0.0, rely=0.4, relheight=1, relwidth=1, anchor='nw')

text_frame=tk.Frame(frame6)
text_frame.place(relx=0, rely=0, relheight=0.6, relwidth=1, anchor='nw')
text=tk.Text(text_frame)
text.place(relx=0, rely=0, relheight=1, relwidth=1, anchor='nw')
vsb=tk.Scrollbar(text_frame)
vsb.pack(side='right',fill='y')
text.config(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
vsb.config(command=text.yview)
# --- frame 6 ---


stop_=True # Stop Flag. True when no measuring is happening

root.mainloop() #here we run our app
# --- main ---
```

Comment: 2 things: First use `"rf".encode()` instead of `str.encode("rf")` (easier to read), second you need to post more code. Also I don't think the problem is in `tkinter`. Also also you have a spelling mistake `stop_` should be `stop` (just guessing) or `stop` should be `stop_`

Comment: @TheLizzard Thank you.. You mean it should be ser.write("rf".encode)? About posting more code, it's 200 lines... So i just placed the relevant code... I feel i might make it bloated.

Comment: `ser.write("rf".encode())` and you oversimplified your code. I have to guess that `cb` is a `tkinter.Entry` and `root` is `tkinter.Tk`. When posting question make sure I can copy/paste your code and be able to reproduce the error/problem. Also why are you calling `global stop` then `stop_ = False`? It makes no sense

Comment: @TheLizzard The problem remains even with these changes. I updated the question with more code.

Comment: @TheLizzard `cb` is a often used abbreviation for `Combobox` ;)

Comment: @TheLizzard I figured out some things. When i change the line `after_id=root.after(100,readSerial)` to  `root.after(100,readSerial)` then the program works kinda. What i mean is that the program works, but only when i receive serial input. For example, if there is a 5 second delay to when arduino sends serial, then the program will freeze, until it receives the data. If the program is minimized, and i select to view it as normal, it will not respond unless it receives input from arduino (which will display normally). Why did i use  `after_id=root.after(100,readSerial)`?

Comment: It is so i can have another button that will cancel the read_serial(). I got this tactic suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66510865/setting-up-the-serial-object-from-a-function-called-from-tkinter-interaction