# Unable to read serial data without errors/bugs

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pyserial

I am writing a small application based on tkinter in order to read serial data from my arduino.
The arduino, when it receives a serial text (`rf`), it will begin sending data to the pc.

Below is the suspicious code:

```
def readSerial():
    ser_bytes = ser.readline()
    ser_bytes = ser_bytes.decode("utf-8")
    text.insert("end", ser_bytes)
    after_id=root.after(100,readSerial)
    #root.after(100,readSerial)


def measure_all():    
   global stop_
   stop_ = False
   ser.write("rf".encode()) #Send string 'rf to arduino', which means Measure all Sensors
   readSerial() #Start Reading data
```

Now this does not work. The program freezes, and no info is revealed on the terminal.

When i change the line `after_id=root.after(100,readSerial)` to `root.after(100,readSerial)` then the program works, but only when i receive serial input.

For example, if there is a 5 second delay to when arduino sends serial, then the program will freeze, until it receives the data. More specificallly, if the program is minimized, and i select to view it as normal, it will not respond unless it receives input from arduino (which will display normally).

So even now, it still does not work properly.

But also have in mind, that i need to have the `after_id` line, so that i can have a handle, so that i can terminate the `readSerial()` function (for example when the user presses the 'stop measurement' button).

Can someone understand what is going on, and how i can have the `after_id` behaviour (so i can stop the continuous function later), while having the program behaving normal, without crashing or stuck until it receives data?

EDIT: This is the modified code after user's acw1668 suggestions. This does not work. I see nothing on the text frame of tkinter.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import serial.tools.list_ports #for a list of all the COM ports
from tkinter import scrolledtext
import threading
import time
from queue import SimpleQueue


#to be used on our canvas
HEIGHT = 800
WIDTH = 800

#hardcoded baud rate
baudRate = 9600

# this is the global variable that will hold the serial object value
ser = None #initial  value. will change at 'on_select()'

after_id = None

#this is the global variable that will hold the value from the dropdown for the sensor select
dropdown_value = None

# create the queue for holding serial data
queue = SimpleQueue()
# flag use to start/stop thread tasks
stop_flag = None


# --- functions ---

#the following two functtions are for the seria port selection, on frame 1

#this function populates the combobox on frame1, with all the serial ports of the system
def serial_ports():
    return serial.tools.list_ports.comports()


#when the user selects one serial port from the combobox, this function will execute
def on_select(event=None):
    global ser
    COMPort = cb.get()
    string_separator = "-"
    COMPort = COMPort.split(string_separator, 1)[0] #remove everything after '-' character
    COMPort = COMPort[:-1] #remove last character of the string (which is a space)
    ser = serial.Serial(port = COMPort, baudrate=9600, timeout=0.1)
    #readSerial() #start reading shit. DELETE. later to be placed in a button
    # get selection from event    
    #print("event.widget:", event.widget.get())
    # or get selection directly from combobox
    #print("comboboxes: ", cb.get())

    #ser = Serial(serialPort , baudRate, timeout=0, writeTimeout=0) #ensure non-blocking


def readSerial(queue):
    global stop_flag
    if stop_flag:
        print("Reading task is already running")
    else:
        print("started")
        stop_flag = threading.Event()
        while not stop_flag.is_set():
            if ser.in_waiting:
                try:
                  ser_bytes = ser.readline()
                  data = ser_bytes.decode("utf-8")
                  queue.put(data)
                except UnicodeExceptionError:
                  print("Unicode Error")
            else:
                time.sleep(0.1)
        print("stopped")
        stop_flag = None




# function to monitor whether data is in the queue
# if there is data, get it and insert into the text box
def data_monitor(queue):
    if not queue.empty():
       text.insert("end", f"{queue.get()}\n")
       if vsb.get()[1]==1.0: #if the scrollbar is down to the bottom, then autoscroll
          text.see("end")
    root.after(100, data_monitor, queue)



    
   


# this function is triggered, when a value is selected from the dropdown
def dropdown_selection(*args):    
   global dropdown_value
   dropdown_value = clicked.get()
   button_single['state'] = 'normal' #when a selection from the dropdown happens, change the state of the 'Measure This Sensor' button to normal


# this function is triggered, when button 'Measure all Sensors' is pressed, on frame 2
def measure_all():    
   button_stop['state']='normal' #make the 'Stop Measurement' button accessible
   ser.write("rf".encode()) #Send string 'rf to arduino', which means Measure all Sensors
   sleep(0.05) # 50 milliseconds
   threading.Thread(target=readSerial, args=(queue,)).start()



# this function is triggered, when button 'Measure this Sensor' is pressed, on frame 2
def measure_single():    
   global stop_
   stop_=False
   button_stop['state']='normal'
   ser.write(dropdown_value.encode()) #Send string 'rf to arduino', which means Measure all Sensors!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
   readSerial()


# this function is triggered, when button 'STOP measurement(s)' is pressed, on frame 2
def stop_measurement():    
    button_stop['state']='disabled'
    ser.write("c".encode())
    if stop_flag:
        stop_flag.set()
    else:
        print("Reading task is not running")
# --- functions ---



# --- main ---
root = tk.Tk() #here we create our tkinter window
root.title("Sensor Interface")

#we use canvas as a placeholder, to get our initial screen size (we have defined HEIGHT and WIDTH)
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

#we use frames to organize all the widgets in the screen

'''
relheight, relwidth − Height and width as a float between 0.0 and 1.0, as a fraction of the height and width of the parent widget.
relx, rely − Horizontal and vertical offset as a float between 0.0 and 1.0, as a fraction of the height and width of the parent widget.
'''

# --- frame 1 ---
frame1 = tk.Frame(root)
frame1.place(relx=0, rely=0.05, relheight=0.03, relwidth=1, anchor='nw') #we use relheight and relwidth to fill whatever the parent is - in this case- root

label0 = tk.Label(frame1, text="Select the COM port that the device is plugged in: ")
label0.config(font=("TkDefaultFont", 8))
label0.place(relx = 0.1, rely=0.3, relwidth=0.3, relheight=0.5)


cb = ttk.Combobox(frame1, values=serial_ports())
cb.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')
# assign function to combobox, that will run when an item is selected from the dropdown
cb.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', on_select)
# --- frame 1 ---



# --- frame 2 ---
frame2 = tk.Frame(root, bd=5) #REMOVED THIS bg='#80c1ff' (i used it to see the borders of the frame)
frame2.place(relx=0, rely=0.1, relheight=0.07, relwidth=1, anchor='nw')

#Button for 'Measure All Sensors'
#it will be enabled initially
button_all = tk.Button(frame2, text="Measure all Sensors", bg='#80c1ff', fg='red', state='normal', command=measure_all)  #bg='gray'
button_all.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.5, anchor='center')

#label
label1 = tk.Label(frame2, text="OR, select a single sensor to measure: ")
label1.config(font=("TkDefaultFont", 9))
label1.place(relx = 0.32, rely=0.3, relwidth=0.3, relheight=0.4)

#dropdown
#OPTIONS = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
OPTIONS = list(range(8)) #[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
clicked = tk.StringVar(master=frame2) # Always pass the `master` keyword argument, in order to run the function when we select from the dropdown
clicked.set(OPTIONS[0]) # default value
clicked.trace("w", dropdown_selection) #When a value from the dropdown is selected, function dropdown_selection() is executed
drop = tk.OptionMenu(frame2, clicked, *OPTIONS)
drop.place(relx = 0.65, rely=0.25, relwidth=0.08, relheight=0.6)

#Button for 'Measure Single Sensor'
#this will be disabled initially, and will be enabled when an item from the dropdown is selected
button_single = tk.Button(frame2, text="Measure this Sensor", bg='#80c1ff', fg='red', state='disabled', command=measure_single) #bg='gray'
button_single.place(relx = 0.85, rely=0.5, anchor='center')
# --- frame 2 ---


# --- frame 3 ---
frame3 = tk.Frame(root, bd=5) #REMOVED THIS bg='#80c1ff' (i used it to see the borders of the frame)
frame3.place(relx=0, rely=0.2, relheight=0.07, relwidth=1, anchor='nw')

#Button for 'STOP Measurement(s)'
#this will be disabled initially, and will be enabled only when a measurement is ongoing
button_stop = tk.Button(frame3, text="STOP measurement(s)", bg='#80c1ff', fg='red', state='disabled', command=stop_measurement)
button_stop.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')
# --- frame 3 ---



# --- frame 4 ---
frame4 = tk.Frame(root, bd=5)
frame4.place(relx=0, rely=0.3, relheight=0.09, relwidth=1, anchor='nw')

label2 = tk.Label(frame4, text="Select a sensor to plot data: ")
label2.place(relx = 0.1, rely=0.3, relwidth=0.3, relheight=0.5)

clickedForPlotting = tk.StringVar()
clickedForPlotting.set(OPTIONS[0]) # default value
dropPlot = tk.OptionMenu(frame4, clickedForPlotting, *OPTIONS)
dropPlot.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')

#CHANGE LATER
#dropDownButton = tk.Button(frame4, text="Plot sensor data", bg='#80c1ff', fg='red', command=single_Sensor) #bg='gray'
#dropDownButton.place(relx = 0.85, rely=0.5, anchor='center')
# --- frame 4 ---


#frame 5 will be the save to txt file


#frame 6 will be the area with the text field
# --- frame 6 ---
frame6 = tk.Frame(root, bg='#80c1ff') #remove color later
frame6.place(relx=0.0, rely=0.4, relheight=1, relwidth=1, anchor='nw')

text_frame=tk.Frame(frame6)
text_frame.place(relx=0, rely=0, relheight=0.6, relwidth=1, anchor='nw')
text=tk.Text(text_frame)
text.place(relx=0, rely=0, relheight=1, relwidth=1, anchor='nw')
vsb=tk.Scrollbar(text_frame)
vsb.pack(side='right',fill='y')
text.config(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
vsb.config(command=text.yview)
# --- frame 6 ---


# start data monitor task
data_monitor(queue)



root.mainloop() #here we run our app
# --- main ---
```

Comment: You need to specify a timeout for the serial read, so the function doesn't hang if there's nothing to receive.  Note that `after_id` is useless the way you have it: it's a local variable, so it's not accessible anywhere else in the program.

Comment: @jasonharper Thank you so much for your comment! I am researching this problem for about a week now.  1. You mean i should set up `global after_id` before my line so it's accessable globally? 2. How do i specify a timeout for the serial read? If my arduino spits data in an interval of five seconds, will the timeout still work, or it will stop the execution of the serial read, and then i will not be able to read the next interval of data coming in?

Comment: You can set `timeout` option when creating instance of `Serial(...)` or use `.in_waiting()` to check whether there is data in the read buffer before reading.

Comment: @acw1668 Thank you. But there is one thing i do not get. My arduino sends data in an interval of 5 seconds. If i set the timeout, then does that mean i can only get one interval of these reading (because the timeout will terminate the connection)?

Comment: The timeout does not terminate the connection, only the current reading action.

Comment: @acw1668 So if the timeout gets triggered, but five seconds later another reading is received, will it get parsed and processed normally?

Comment: You call `readSerial()` every 100ms periodically, so basically yes.

Comment: @acw1668 I am a bit confused... So i just basically set the timeout? Or there is extra logic that i have to implement? When the program is set to the 'receiving data' logic (through the press of a button in tkinter), do i have to include extra logic to restart the function when (and if) the timeout occurs?

Comment: When timeout on `ser.readline()`, it just returns an empty byte string.  Have you ever tried the timeout or using `.in_waiting`?

Comment: @acw1668 Thank you for trying to help me but i confused and stuck. I am opening a bounty.

Comment: @user1584421 You can go through the docs [here](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html), `timeout` has been explained well.

Comment: @AST But how can i also incorporate the `id` functionality so i can terminate it with a stop button? Is the behavior described in the question normal?

Comment: @user1584421 The behaviour described is pretty normal as `ser.readline()` is blocking, and any blocking function when used in `tkinter` will freeze the mainloop. Setting the `timeout` parameter makes it non-blocking (as also described in the docs). You can use the "`id` functionality" normally then after.

Comment: @AST i tried a `timeout=0.1` and it worked great the first time, but it never worked again. Mostly the software just got stuck, no info on the terminal. However, two times i got errors on the terminal. The first time it said `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfe in position 0: invalid start byte` on this line: `ser_bytes = ser_bytes.decode("utf-8")`. The second time i got `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'` on this line: `ser.write("rf".encode())`. Do you have any clues on these? Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to use thread instead of `.after()`?

Comment: @acw1668 no.. I haven't received this recommendation before, this is the first time i am hearing this. How exactly do i use this? Do you think this is the source of my new problems? It's weird that the program worked just fine once but never again....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to not blocking the main tkinter application, it is recommended to use thread to run the serial reading.  Also use `queue.SimpleQueue` to transfer the serial data to main task so that the serial data can be inserted into the `Text` widget.

Below is an example:

```py
import threading
import time
from queue import SimpleQueue
import tkinter as tk
import serial

class SerialReader(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, ser, queue, *args, **kw):
        super().__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.ser = ser
        self.queue = queue
        self._stop_flag = threading.Event()

    def run(self):
        print("started")
        while not self._stop_flag.is_set():
            if self.ser.in_waiting:
                ser_bytes = self.ser.readline()
                data = ser_bytes.decode("utf-8")
                self.queue.put(data)
            else:
                time.sleep(0.1)
        print("stopped")

    def terminate(self):
        self._stop_flag.set()

# create the serial instance
ser = serial.Serial(port="COM1") # provide other parameters as well
# create the queue for holding serial data
queue = SimpleQueue()
# the serial reader task
reader = None

def start_reader():
    global reader
    if reader is None:
        # create the serial reader task
        reader = SerialReader(ser, queue, daemon=True)
    if not reader.is_alive():
        # start the serial reader task
        reader.start()
    else:
        print("Reader is already running")

def stop_reader():
    global reader
    if reader and reader.is_alive():
        # stop the serial reader task
        reader.terminate()
        reader = None
    else:
        print("Reader is not running")

# function to monitor whether data is in the queue
# if there is data, get it and insert into the text box
def data_monitor(queue):
    if not queue.empty():
        text.insert("end", f"{queue.get()}\n")
    root.after(100, data_monitor, queue)

root = tk.Tk()

text = tk.Text(root, width=80, height=20)
text.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root)
tk.Button(frame, text="Start", command=start_reader).pack(side="left")
tk.Button(frame, text="Stop", command=stop_reader).pack(side="left")
frame.pack()

# start data monitor task
data_monitor(queue)

root.mainloop()
```

---

Update@2021-04-16: Example without using class

```
import threading
import time
from queue import SimpleQueue
import tkinter as tk
import serial

# create the serial instance
ser = serial.Serial(port="COM1") # provide other parameters as well
# create the queue for holding serial data
queue = SimpleQueue()
# flag use to start/stop thread tasks
stop_flag = None

def readSerial(queue):
    global stop_flag
    if stop_flag:
        print("Reading task is already running")
    else:
        print("started")
        stop_flag = threading.Event()
        while not stop_flag.is_set():
            if ser.in_waiting:
                ser_bytes = ser.readline()
                data = ser_bytes.decode("utf-8")
                queue.put(data)
            else:
                time.sleep(0.1)
        print("stopped")
        stop_flag = None

def start_reader():
    threading.Thread(target=readSerial, args=(queue,)).start()

def stop_reader():
    if stop_flag:
        stop_flag.set()
    else:
        print("Reading task is not running")

# function to monitor whether data is in the queue
# if there is data, get it and insert into the text box
def data_monitor(queue):
    if not queue.empty():
        text.insert("end", f"{queue.get()}\n")
    root.after(100, data_monitor, queue)

root = tk.Tk()

text = tk.Text(root, width=80, height=20)
text.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root)
tk.Button(frame, text="Start", command=start_reader).pack(side="left")
tk.Button(frame, text="Stop", command=stop_reader).pack(side="left")
frame.pack()

# start data monitor task
data_monitor(queue)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you. I will check the code in some hours. However, is there a way to do this without using classes? I find it complicated that we have function declarations, and then function declarations inside the class. One more question, do you think this approach will also handle the errors, that i got yesterday, that are referenced in my comment?

Comment: @user1584421 Answer updated with example not using class.  For the errors you mentioned in your comment, they are related to the data sent from the arduino.  You can try not calling `decode("utf-8")` on the data returned.

Comment: Thank you. I run some experiments today, and the behavior is completely inexplicable. I made a question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67144017/inconsistent-serial-fails. Can you please take a look at it, and tell me if your implementation will solve those errors? Because if i have to do your implementation, i have to redesign the program from the ground up and make a lot of changes. If you believe those problems will be solved by your implementation, please let me know. Thank you,

Comment: Sorry but your code did not work. I updated my question with your version of the code i used.