# Inconsistent serial fails

Tags: python-3.x, serial-port, pyserial

I am trying to develop a python tkinter based app that would read the data from my arduino sensor platform.

I am getting inconsistent errors that i can't understand why this happens.

First of all, this is the code that is to blame:

```
def readSerial():
   print("1")
   global after_id
   print("2")
   ser_bytes = ser.readline()
   print("3")
   ser_bytes = ser_bytes.decode("utf-8")
   print("4")
   text.insert("end", ser_bytes)
   print("5")
   after_id = root.after(50, readSerial)
```

1. Sometimes this works. The data appear on my tkinter frame, as the characters 1,2,3,4,5 keep scrolling down in the terminal. This is the rarest case.

[image]

2. Other times the terminal printing keeps on going down, but nothing appears on my tkinter text frame. When i press the read button again, the numbers stop printing in the terminal, but the text from the serial appear on my tkinter frame. How is this possible i cannot understand.
3. Some times the terminal printing keeps on going down, but nothing appears on my tkinter text frame. If i press the 'start reading' button again, the program will get stuck, the button will remain gray, the print in the terminal will stop.

[image]

4. Other times i get freeze for some reason. Make the program will freeze, or the stop button will make it freeze.

Not only i cannot understand why the behaviors except (1) - the normal case occur, i don't understand why there is no consistency in what behavior will be triggered. When behavior 2, or 3 or 4 will happen and why? What triggers each specific behavior?

Can someone understand what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

I would ask myself about your setup (which I don't know what the circuit is):

1. have you tested your code with test data that works independently of a link to your Arduino.
2. have you checked the validity of the data coming from the Arduino.
3. what measures are you taking to avoid noise being introduce with your data input.

Comment: The arduino works fine. And i can gather data fine from the serial interface of the arduino IDE.

Comment: @user1584421  The 7th line of your function reads: ser_bytes = sre_bytes.decode("utf-8"), should it not read: ser_bytes = ser_bytes.decode("utf-8")?

Comment: thanks but that error was when i typed the code here, It doesnt exist in my code, so this is not the origin of the error.